# comparing Numpy arrays raises a.any() or a.all() error

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying the following code to check if elements of numpy array are found in another 'b' list but i get the following error

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

i tried looking it up but couldn't get it to work

how to use a.all() or other methods like numpy.logical_and in this example

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]])
b=[]

for item in a :
    if item not in b:
       b.append(item)`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it without loops:

```
b = np.unique(a, axis=0)
```

This is orders of magnitude faster, and more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Solution provided by @John Zwinck is probably the best for this problem. I'm commenting on the loop approach if for some reason one has to use it.

The problem with loop approach is the way the `in` and the array test for equality work.

Grosso modo, `item in b` compares `item` with the elements in `b` using equality (`==`). Something like:

```
def in(x, y):
    for item in y:
        # Notice the use of == to compare two arrays, the result is an array of bool.
        if x == item:
            return True
    return False
```

So if one can't use np.unique and definitively needs to use a loop, then implement an variation of `in` to compare two arrays.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]])
b=[]

def in_for_arrays(x, y):
    for item in y:
        # Two arrays are equal if ALL the elements are equal.
        if (x == item).all():
            return True
    return False


for item in a:
    if not in_for_arrays(item, b):
        b.append(item)
```